# MAAS, JUJU help: MAAS Nodes have no access to the internet while PXE booting

Tags: 12.04, juju, maas, pxe

We are trying to implement a cloud setup in our college using MAAS/Juju/OpenStack.

The college has its own DHCP server and we don't have access to that. So, we can't set next-server to our MAAS server. The problem of booting the nodes was solved by getting our own switch and allowing MAAS server to run DHCP. Since there is only one NIC, when we connect our machines to the switch, we have no access to the internet.

So, here's what we've done till now.

1. Installed MAAS on a machine along with DHCP/DNS.
2. Added the MAC addresses of three other machines through MAAS Web Interface.
3. PXE booted the other machines.

Although the nodes do PXE boot, they are unable to download the packages as they are no longer connected to the internet. So, the OS components are not installed. The MAAS server however sets the nodes to 'Ready' and I can bootstrap Juju on it.

What is a work around for this?

We can't get NICs for all the machines although getting one for the Master Server is possible.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add a second NIC to the master server, and enable IPv4 forwarding and NAT, you can use the second NIC to connect to the switch and all the other machines, while using the first NIC on the server to access the outside, both for the server and the machines.

You might find this useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: Thank You dimitern. Sorry, I am new to this. We were trying out setting up a NAT when someone suggested that we install IPCOP on another server and use it as a proxy to access the internet from an internal network. It worked. I've marked this answer as accepted. Thank you. :)